# Calling express API from different domain

Tags: javascript, express

I'm new to Express.js, and making APIs. I'm pretty confused. I am trying to set up a rest api on my domain, so that I can put in http://example.com:3000/api/endpoint, and then have it return data from a database that is running on my domain. The express api is running on my domain. However, typing in the url to the endpoint does not work to return the data I want.  However, when I ssh into my domain and run

curl http://localhost:3000/api/endpoint

the data that I want is printed out. How do I get the express api to work not just on "localhost", but on the domain that it is running on, so I can type in the domain itself and get the data I want back?

Thanks!

Comment: deploy it on some server. `heroku` etc.

Comment: What message are you getting when trying: http://example.com:3000/api/endpoint? And where are you hosting your express app?

Comment: Your domain needs to point to the public IP address of your server AND that server needs to be available from the open internet.  If this is running on your home network, then one or both of these is probably an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at `ngrok`. It's just one option that allows you to run something on localhost but allow it to be available externally.

https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're running into CORS issues here?

You said you have it deployed somewhere (I assume externally accessible) but you cannot query it from (I assume) a browser?

If that's the case, read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. You can add CORS to your ExpressJS app by installing this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors